# My server wont start,ruby on rails mac

Tags: ruby

> Blockquote

When i try to run bin/rails server,my server wont start up it will just display some connection errors or whatever.I tried bundle exec rails server  but it didnt work either.

```
Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/i/blog/config/routes.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `resources' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/i/blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/i/blog/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /Users/i/blog/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/i/blog/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/i/blog/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/i/blog/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/i/blog/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/i/blog/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

heres my config/routes file

> Rails.application.routes.draw do
>       resources :articles
>       root 'welcome#index'
>   end
>   resources :articles do
>   resources :comments
>   end

Comment: Can you please share more info about error that you've got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read stacktraces from the top to understand wat is going on:

```
Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
```

This is just a warning, you may want to fix that later. But you can ignore that at the moment, since it is just a warning.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

This is the default output when Rails boots.

But now the interesting part:

```
Exiting
/Users/i/blog/config/routes.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `resources' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

This line tells you that you have a `undefined method 'resources'` in the `7`th line (or before that line) of your `config/routes.rb`.

The problem is caused by the second `resources :articles` block that is not within the outer `Rails.application.routes.draw` block. Furthermore you have two `resources :articles`, but you only need one. Copy the following version to `config/routes.rb` to fix your issue:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#index'

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you.I edited my question and posted that routes.rb file.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that if possible